# Running an R bat file that connects to KDB to query data

Tags: r, dll, interface, kdb

I am struggling to execute my bat file. I have narrowed by problem down to the fact that it fails due to the connection with KDB. I'm using the files in w64_qserver [here](http://code.kx.com/wsvn/code/cookbook_code/r/w64_qserver/?#aab6bb31e13bc2816b2db913b3fc5017c) to query the data from KDB. Under normal circumstances I can happily query my data from KDB and play with it in R. But it doesnt run when I set up a .bat file. I think my problem is that I didnt specify the path to the .dll file in my batch file correctly. Below is the batch file I am running, thank you for your time:

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\r
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1\bin\R.exe" CMD BATCH --vanilla --slave "C:\Users\Desktop\NEW TASK Executables\execute1.R"
pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should point it to 64bit version of R.

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.2\bin\x64\R.exe" CMD BATCH --vanilla --slave "C:\Users\Desktop\NEW TASK Executables\execute1.R"
```